# Problema al mostrar una variable en laravel a partir del query de sql

Tags: laravel, eloquent

tengo un problema con un código es bastante sencillo pero no consigo dar en el clavo, os explico un poco, se trata de una variable que recoge la suma de todos los campos "desplazamiento" con la id exacta de un proyecto.

código:

```
 $km = ParteTrabajo::select( DB::raw('SUM(desplazamiento)'),)->where('proyecto_id', $id )->get();
  return $km;
```

El problema reside en que el return me devuelve **[{"SUM(desplazamiento)":106.01}]** y yo necesito solo que me devuelva el **106.01**,

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes:

- Reformular tu consulta, incluyendo:

  - Usar uno de los [métodos de agregación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates), dentro de dicho método pasas como argumento el nombre de la columna de la cual quieres obtener la sumatoria
  - Agregar al método `where()` el nombre de la columna a evaluar *(aunque esto es opcional y no determinar el resultado deseado)*

Quedando la consulta así:

```
$km = ParteTrabajo::whereProyectoId($id)->sum("desplazamiento");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo :D